# select2 not working inside angularjs tabs

Tags: angularjs, tabs

i have angularjs tab and i need select2 inside one of them.select2 woking in all of my page but not inside tab.
parts of tab code is:

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="MetaIndicators.tpl.html" >
                    <div class="row col-xs-12" style=" margin-right:10px;margin-top:22px"  >
                        <div class="form-group inline col-xs-12">
                            <div class=" form-group inline meta-form-groups col-xs-12">
                                <label class="metaLabels">ژانر</label>
                                <textarea name="Genre" data-kind="1" type="text" class=" form-control inline" ng-model="indicators1" ng-bind="indicators1" style="width:400px;float:right" readonly/>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger inline" style="margin-right: 35px;margin-top: 8px;"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#send-modal-IndicatorsGenre" ng-show="AllowEdit">ویرایش</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                    <div class="modal fade" id="send-modal-IndicatorsGenre" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" style="background-color: white; margin-top: 100px;height: 179px; width:680px;">
                            <div class="modal-body" style="height:80%">
                                <form id="metaIndicatorsGenreInsert" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:8px;">
                                            <label for="GenreID" class="col-xs-1 control-label" style="width:59px">ژانر</label>
                                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                                                <select multiple id="e1"  style="width:500px">
                                                    <option></option>
                                                    <option ng-repeat="gn in GenreID"  value="{{ gn.Key }}" ng-model="gn.Value">{{ gn.Value }}</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <hr class="stylish" />
                                    <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:20px;">
                                        <a href="#" data-id="" data-name="openModal" data-task="submit" data-forms="#formMetaIndicatorsGenreInsert" data-method="post" data-action="InsertMetaIndicatorsGenre" data-results="#send-results" data-identifier="do-send" class="btn btn-success pull-right "><i class="fa fa-mail-forward"></i> ثبت </a>
                                        <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default pull-left">انصراف</a>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </script>
```

i add select2.min.js and select2.min.css to index .

function of fill select is :

```
 function GetGenreListData() {
    var Genre = metaService.CallService('get', "basic/GenreID", "");
    Genre.success(function (data) {
        $scope.GenreID = data;
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        alert($cookies.get('searchedMeta') + data.status);
    });
}
```

and function of setting select2 is :

```
  $("#e1").select2({
    closeOnSelect: false
});
```

thanks alot

Comment: Do you get `data` in your request? What structure does it have?

Comment: yes i get data from request and fill json to options.with ajax call

Comment: This looks strange - `ng-model="gn.Value"`. You should set `ng-model` on  `select` element, not on `option`. And it should be some scope variable. See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Comment: thank you but this not working